# Regex Matching Custom HTTP Header

Tags: regex

I have a **full text** of HTTP header like this:

```
GET /index.php HTTP/1.1
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-ACCESS: 123456
```

So I want to create a regex which checks if X-ACCESS is exists and equals to 123456, how should I write it?

EDIT: I do not need to control the value of **123456**, that is as long as `X-ACCESS: 123456` is presented, regex will be true.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why regex? This will suffice:

```
if (stripos ($http_header_text, 'X-ACCESS: 123456') !== false) {
    echo 'Custom header is here and is good';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) Well I only want regex because it's not in the programming environment, web server instead.

Comment: @GreenVine you used `php` tag, so I assume you can use php. If yes, then can use the code above.

Comment: does it checks this `and equals to 123456` condition?

Comment: @AvinashRaj ofc it does. `stripos()` returns true if entire `X-ACCESS: 123456` is found. if there is `X-ACCESS: 121212` it will return false.

Comment: i think op wants to check the value of `X-ACCESS:` with the value stored inside another variable.

Comment: @AvinashRaj he only said that he wants to check if its set and equals to pregiven value. I may be wrong, but thats how he stated his question imho.

Comment: @Forien, sorry I just ignored that tag automatically generated

Comment: I'm not an http expert but.... as far as I believe, a field like `X-ACCESS: 123456` can be expressed like: `x-AcCesS         :            123456` So a regexp is better than plain string comparing. (sorry, I used several spaces at either side of colon, but only one is shown)  A regexp like `[xX]-[aA][cC][cC][eE][sS][sS][\t ]*:[\t ]*(123456)[\t ]*\r\n' would be better than simple string comparison. (I used the parenthesis around `123456` to access `$1` as the content to be checked for?)

Comment: If you can guarantee that you won't get other, arbitrary headers, then this is fine. It will give you invalid results though if headers are submitted whose key ends with `X-ACCESS` and whose value starts with `123456` (e.g., `X-I-HAVE-MAX-ACCESS: 1234567-is-the-number-I-use`).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `preg_match` function.

```
$str = <<<EOT
GET /index.php HTTP/1.1
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-ACCESS: 123456
EOT;
if(preg_match('~^X-ACCESS:\h*123456$~m', $str)) {

        echo "Yep, they are equal";
}
```

`\h*` will match zero or more horizontal white-space character, you could use `\s*` also.

Comment: why not check for '123456' within regex already? Or why don't just check `stripos` or `stristr`?

Comment: Can you provide a regex checks 123456 within the regex like @Forien said? That is as long as `X-ACCESS: 123456` is presented regex is true

Comment: @GreenVine the simpliest regex for that is `X-ACCESS: 123456`.

Comment: @Forien You are absolutely right `X-ACCESS: 123456` is the simplest regex, just made it complicated :lol

Comment: but this `X-ACCESS: 123456` regex will match also `foobarX-ACCESS: 12345673647634` :lol